# Excel 2010 - Using multiple IF OR statements to return different values

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010

I am trying to change a number in a cell based on the text entered in another cell.
This is working when using two values (see Rows 4 + 5 in image)

```
=IF(J5="L",I5,(I5-0.5))*OR(IF(B5="Flexi",0,(I5-0.5)))
```

However I cannot get it to work with three (see Row 6 in image)

```
=IF(J6="L",I6,(I6-0.5))*OR(IF(B6="Flexi",0,(I6-0.5))*OR(IF(B6="Half",3.7,(I6-0.5))))
```

Cell K6 should now have a value of 3.7 however it does not change.

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLfgg.png)

[Excel with formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZCmF.png)

Thanks

Comment: check with `=IF(J6="L",I6,IF(B6="Flexi",0,IF(B6="Half",3.7,0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check with below formula

```
=IF(J6="L",I6,IF(B6="Flexi",0,IF(B6="Half",3.7,(I6-0.5))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your argument and according to the images none of the arguments are true,
for you to get that result you have to edit the argument as,

```
=IF(J7="L",I7,(I7-0.5))*OR(IF(B7="Flexi",0,(I7-0.5))*OR(IF(B6="Half",3.7,(I7-0.5))))
```

here the difference is in the third OR statement. "Half" is in B6 not in B7 that's why it is not working.

Comment: Good spot, that was me copying and pasting it wrong for the screenshot. However this does not solve the issue I am having. I have updated my question.